# Text of the button loses its sharpening and slightly blurred in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Persian language and I have developed two ways to display my button in Bootstrap 3.3.6:

[image]

For the upper I have used this code:

```
    <div class="row text-center">
        <button type="button" id="submitFace" class="btn btn-primary"> <h4><font face="B Nazanin">
            خواندن اطلاعات چهره
        </font></h4></button>
    </div>
```

And for the lower I have used this code:

```
    //--------in the CSS-------
    @font-face{
        font-family: myFirstFont;
        src: url("../myFonts/BNAZANIN.TTF");
    }
    .myButton{
        font-family: myFirstFont;
        font-size: large;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    //---------in the HTML-------
    <div class="row text-center">
        <button type="button" id="submitFace" class="btn btn-primary myButton">
            خواندن اطلاعات چهره
        </button>
    </div>
```

However, as you see in the picture when I use CSS the result has not a good sharpening. I mean border of the text is not clear, if you look closely you see that the text of the button is slightly blurred.

---

**I have found that** even though we use a `myButton` class without any styles, and instead we set inline styles like the upper code, it still remains blurred!!!

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by 'good sharpening'?

Comment: I mean border of the text is not clear, look closely to the picture you understand. Text of the button is slightly blurred.

Comment: I think issue is with your custom font - myFirstFont. Try replacing that font-family with default font.

Comment: I don't want to change my favorite font, however I change this famous font with another but the problem exist

Comment: See if it helps - http://plnkr.co/edit/kVgpRbZOWT9O6GcblSW9?p=preview

Comment: `<strong>` tag did not help

Answer (score 4):

Ensure `text-shadow: none` is set.

Comment: I have add this to CSS of `myButton`, but does not work

Comment: Is the font you are calling already bold? Explicitly setting `font-weight: bold` when `normal` is more appropriate could be it, or how about adjusting the size by a small amount?

Comment: Yes, I know that. Is this appropriate to the inherent weight of the font you are using though? A font that is already bold should have its font-weight set to normal in CSS. There's a subtlety in what I'm (failing) to explain.

Comment: Had same issue in Web2Py framework. (See https://github.com/web2py/web2py/issues/1083). Using Karl's suggestion within the button definition (not the CSS) - solved the problem of blurred text when btn-primary.

Comment: `text-shadow: none` fixed the blurry font for me on a Bootstrap 4 button

Answer (score 0):

Please try this css

text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important; -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this issue.

This issue comes from not having a bold font available for the font you have embedded. You need to include the bold version of the font or the browser will try to render the bold version of the font badly.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have

> overflow-x hidden

;) That's how I fixed it!
I found the solution by turning off in the chrome checkboxes the style panel at my element submit button and the styles aplied to the button too from other parent elements.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).